# NodeJS crash with multiple request

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, crash

My nodejs server crashes randomly in real time ( and always on Web Stress Tool with 10+ thread request). Below is the code that I believe to be the root cause.

**main.js**

```
--------
app = express():
---------
app.get('/image/*', actions.download);
```

**actions.js**

```
var request = require('request');
exports.download = function(req, res){
var url = <Amazon s3 URL>;
req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
};
```

**When server crashes, I am getting below error in nohup**

```
stream.js:94
throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
^
Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (http.js:1476:15)
at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1572:23)
at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:943:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

**Detailed log when I tried with `sudo NODE_DEBUG=net node main.js` and subjected to stress test with 10 threads**

```
NET: 3017 Socket._read readStart 
NET: 3017 afterWrite 0 { domain: null, bytes: 335, oncomplete: [Function: afterWrite] } 
NET: 3017 afterWrite call cb 
NET: 3017 onread ECANCELED 164640 4092 168732
NET: 2983 got data
NET: 2983 onSocketFinish
NET: 2983 oSF: not ended, call shutdown()
NET: 2983 destroy undefined
NET: 2983 destroy
NET: 2983 close
NET: 2983 close handle
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:558:19)
```

Comment: How much requests for second?

Comment: Requests are taking around 100~300ms.

I got it working flawlessly by changing `req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)` to `request(url).pipe(res)`
Initial implementation was based on [request](https://github.com/request/request) tutorial. It is working for normal conditions but crashing server when there is a pool of simultaneous requests. Wondering whether the fix is right even though issue resolved !

Answer (score 0):

This is cased by `libuv` in [src/unix/stream.c](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v0.10/src/unix/stream.c#L488). Here we have:

```
if (stream->shutdown_req) {
  /* The UV_ECANCELED error code is a lie, the shutdown(2) syscall is a
   * fait accompli at this point. Maybe we should revisit this in v0.11.
   * A possible reason for leaving it unchanged is that it informs the
   * callee that the handle has been destroyed.
   */
  uv__req_unregister(stream->loop, stream->shutdown_req);
  uv__set_artificial_error(stream->loop, UV_ECANCELED);
  stream->shutdown_req->cb(stream->shutdown_req, -1);
  stream->shutdown_req = NULL;
}
```

I've found the reason of this problem:

1. `stream->shutdown_req` was assigned by `int uv_shutdown(`. So someone called `uv_shutdown`. Who called `uv_shutdown`?
2. `uv_shutdown` is not a simple function. See [here](https://gist.github.com/andrew-aladev/3fad5494f854c910ed642038a2d2a108). The name of this function is `StreamWrap::Shutdown`.
3. `StreamWrap::Shutdown` is used in `nodejs`: `SET_INSTANCE_METHOD("shutdown", StreamWrap::Shutdown, 0)`. `shutdown` method is a part of `wrappers/pipe_wrap` and `wrappers/tcp_wrap`
4. So someone called `shutdown` from `nodejs/lib`. It can be `lib/net` and `lib/tls`.
5. So `shutdown` is called from `function onCryptoStreamFinish` or `function onSocketFinish`.

So you need to find who sent shutdown request in your case. `onread ECANCELED` means that stream (for example socket1.pipe(socket2)) has been killed.

BTW I think that you can workaround your issue by using special technique to destroy piped sockets from [lib/tls](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_tls_legacy.js):

```
pair.encrypted.on('close', function() {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    // Encrypted should be unpiped from socket to prevent possible
    // write after destroy.
    pair.encrypted.unpipe(socket);
    socket.destroy();
  });
});
```